# how to redirect page after submission of form in javascript with an alert too

Tags: javascript

I am trying to redirect after form submission but even though the code seems correct it does not redirect. What could be the problem?

The below is the snippet. There's no error in my console when I try running this code. Any help?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>CHECK BOX</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="confirmation.css">
</head>
<body>
<script>
    function confirm(){
        if(document.getElementById('agree').checked) {
            alert('Registration Successful');
            setTimeout(function() {              //This function set the time for redirecting to 2 seconds after user click ok
                window.location("dashboard.html");
                //            window.location.href = "dashboard.html";
            }, 3000);
            return true;
        } else {
            alert('Please read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy');
            return false;
        }

    }

</script>


<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="confirm()">
    <label>Username</label><br />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username"  placeholder="Enter your Username"  maxlength="30" required="" />
    <br />
    <label>Phone Number</label><br />
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phoneNumber"  placeholder="Enter your Phone Number"  maxlength="14" required="" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="check" id="agree" /> I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditionsand Privacy Policy
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `action` form attribute must be set to the location of the redirect. You don't do it with `window.location` when it happens after a form's submission.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to redirect after a form has been submitted. Currently, even if your redirect did work, the form data would not be transmitted anywhere. A `form` element has an `action` attribute for you to indicate where it should redirect and send the form data to.

Your code seems to just provide some form validation, which is handled differently than what you are attempting.

Here's how it should be set up. (Make sure to read all the HTML and JavaScript comments):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>CHECK BOX</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="confirmation.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- The action attribute is where you set the location of the redirect. -->
  <!-- Don't use HTML event attributes to set up events. Do it in JavaScript. -->
  <form action="dashboard.html" method="post">
    <!-- A label should have a for attribute that points to the id of the element it is for. -->
    <label for="username">Username</label><br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username"  placeholder="Enter your Username"  maxlength="30" required="" />
    <br>
    <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label><br />
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phoneNumber"  placeholder="Enter your Phone Number"  maxlength="14" required="" />
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="check" id="agree"> I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditionsand Privacy Policy
    <br>
    <!-- Don't name any form elements "submit" as it will overwrite the form.submit() function -->
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="submit">

  </form>
  
  <!-- It's generally a best-practice to place script elements just before
       the closing body tag so that the page doesn't get blocked while loading
       and to ensure that the DOM will have been parsed by the time the script runs. -->
  <script>
    let frm = document.querySelector("form");
    frm.addEventListener("submit", confirm);
  
    // Event handling functions will always be passed a reference to the event
    // they are handling. You should set up a function argument to capture that reference.
    // Once you have captured the reference, you can cancel the event if needed.
    function confirm(evt){
        
        // Normally, we only want to cancel the form's submit event if validation fails
        // but, since you want a delay, we need to do it.
        evt.preventDefault();
        
        if(document.getElementById('agree').checked) {
            alert('Registration Successful');
            setTimeout(function() {
              frm.submit(); // Submit the form, which will allow it to redirect to the action
            }, 3000);
        } else {
            alert('Please read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy');
        }
    }
  </script>  
</body>
</html>
```